# GCC compile with mysql library

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

when I try to compile a self written project in C with includes the mysql libraries I get this error:

```
gcc -c src/oDAO.c
src/oDAO.c:4:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
```

I included the my_global.h as following:

```
#include <my_global.h>
```

The error comes up, because my system copied the header files to /usr/include/mysql/ and gcc is searching for system header files only in /usr/include (without subdirectories). How can I call gcc with adding /usr/include/mysql as additional shared library root?

Here is my acutal Makefile:

```
all: main.o oDAO.o FileUtils.o DVDDAO.o
    gcc -Llib -o oDAO main.o oDAO.o FileUtils.o DVDDAO.o -llinkedlist -lncurses `mysql_config --cflags --libs` 

main.o:
    gcc -c src/main.c

oDAO.o:
    gcc -c src/oDAO.c

FileUtils.o:
    gcc -c src/FileUtils.c

DVDDAO.o:
    gcc -c src/DVDDAO.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f oDAO
    rm -f *.bak
    rm -f *.~
```

Comment: you need to use mysql_config to get the correct compile and link flags.

Comment: There is a swich, I know it... Did you look into the man page of gcc?

Comment: To be honest: The man page of gcc is too big for me to understand everything and find the thing i am actually looking for...

Comment: @pausch the switches are -I and -L I found them in one of my make files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer on my own:

Everytime i try to compile a .c file that includes a mysql library into an object file I have to compile it like that:

```
gcc -c DVDDAO.c `mysql_config --cflags`
```

Then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try the option `-I` for adding a include directory and `-L` for adding a libary directory.